# Echo Usage if they don't put parameters correct

Tags: bash

I have this

```
USAGE="Usage: -f [file name] -c [column] -v [value] ."

while getopts ":f:c:v: " OPTIONS; do
    case $OPTIONS in
            f ) file=$OPTARG;;
            c ) column=$OPTARG;;
            v ) value=$OPTARG;;
            h ) echo $USAGE;;
            \? ) echo $USAGE
                     exit 1;;
            * ) echo $USAGE
                    exit 1;;
    esac
done
```

the filename is fun2.sh ... I want to echo the $USAGE if they fail to put a parameter in -f or -c or -v.

I have tryied putting a

```
" ") echo $USAGE
exit1;;
```

but that didn't work..

I also tried

```
if [ $file || $column || $value == "" ]
echo $USAGE
```

but then again it didn't work..

Any Help would be appreciated

EDIT

What worked for me

```
if [ "$file" == "" ] ;
then
echo $USAGE
elif [ "$column" == "" ];
then
echo $USAGE
elif [ "$value" == "" ];
then
echo $USAGE
else
show_column
check_temp
file_move
write_file
```

Answer (score 2):

Try:

```
[[ -z "$file" || -z "$column" || -z "$value" ]] && echo "$USAGE" && exit
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't do this in the loop. Check the values of the variables after the loop and print `$USAGE` if they are empty or the values are wrong (not an integer, for example).

Comment: i tried this and it didn't work

`code`
    if [[ -n "$file" ]] ; then
    echo $USAGE
    elif [[ -n "$column" ]] ; then
    echo $USAGE
    elif [[ -n "$value" ]] ; then
    echo $USAGE
    else
    show_column
    check_temp
    file_move
    write_file
    fi

Comment: Don't forget to `exit` after the `echo`.

Comment: @John the `-n` test is true if the string is *not* empty, i.e. you're printing the error if any of the parameters is supplied, not if any is missing.  Use `-z` instead, as in @dogbane's answer.

Answer (score 0):

Not entirely sure why your code doesn't work, but this should:

```
USAGE="Usage: -f [file name] -c [column] -v [value] ."

params="$(getopt -o f:c:v:h --name "$(basename -- "$0")" -- "$@")"

if [ $? -ne 0 ]
then
    echo "$USAGE"
    exit 1
fi

eval set -- "$params"

while true
do
    case $1 in
        -f)
            file="$2"
            shift 2
            ;;
        -c)
            column="$2"
            shift 2
            ;;
        -v)
            value="$2"
            shift 2
            ;;
        -h)
            echo "$USAGE"
            exit
            ;;
        --)
            shift
            break
            ;;
        *)
            echo "$USAGE"
            exit 1
            ;;
    esac
done
```

Comment: He also wants to print the usage if "$file" is empty or "-c" (i.e. when the parameter is missing).

Answer (score 0):

John, i dont understand what is a bad with your code: In my bash got the following: (the name of script is "go") - OK mean, got what i expected.

```
jonatan:shell clt$ ./go
#ok

jonatan:shell clt$ ./go ewdwedw
#ok

jonatan:shell clt$ ./go -a
Usage: -f [file name] -c [column] -v [value] .
#ok, -a is incorrect

jonatan:shell clt$ ./go -f
Usage: -f [file name] -c [column] -v [value] .
#ok, -f need an argument

jonatan:shell clt$ ./go -f aaa
#ok, -f has an argiment

jonatan:shell clt$ ./go -c
Usage: -f [file name] -c [column] -v [value] .
jonatan:shell clt$ ./go -c -v
#hm -  "-v" comes into `column`, so syntactically is ok, but ....
```

Therefore you need another check - as you done already. So, your script is OK.

Here is my "go".

```
#!/bin/bash

USAGE="Usage: -f [file name] -c [column] -v [value] ."

while getopts ":f:c:v:" OPTIONS; do
    case "$OPTIONS" in
            f ) file=$OPTARG;;
            c ) column=$OPTARG;;
            v ) value=$OPTARG;;
            h ) echo $USAGE;;
            \? ) echo $USAGE; exit 1;;
            * ) echo $USAGE; exit 1;;
    esac
done
```